# Tutorial for Gmail authentication in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, c#-4.0, gmail

I 'm building an application in ASP.NET MVC which should use Gmail authentication and I don't know where to start. Are there any good tutorials or sample code I can use?

Comment: The idea here is to help you correct/level-up your code. What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [blog post](http://andrewblogs.com/blog/openid-for-asp-net-mvc-a-quick-setup/) which illustrates how you could use the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) library to authenticate with an OpenID provider.

Comment: thanx for the response, Is there any way to implement GData for authentication